# Shared data between class-objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple classes (running simultaneously using threads). They all need to access one dictionary/object (containing configuration values from a database, and references to all other objects, to be able to call methods between 2 threads)

What would be the best way to implement this?
Should I create a module which holds and gets the data?
A global variable?

I'm pretty new to Python and I feel like im approaching this the wrong way

**Edit** (small example script)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.3

class foo(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        # access config from here
        y = bar(name='test').start()

        while True:
            pass
    def test(self):
        print('hello world')

class bar(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        # access config from here
        # access x.test() from here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = foo(name='Main').start()
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? It depends on what you're trying to implement.

Comment: @JoelCornett I've added a small example.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what your trying to accomplish, but it seems to me that you can pass the method `test` to `y` when you instantiate it. Of course you'd have to modify the inherited constructor `bar.__init__()` to accept and store arguments.

Comment: @JoelCornett I modified the constructors once but I ended up having lots of parameters on a bunch of threads (9 at the moment). Is this the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program is big enough, with lots of global data, it would be a good idea to create a module and put all your global data there. Import this module from your other modules and use it. If the program is small, then perhaps a global variable is more appropriate. I assume here this will be a read-only structure, otherwise things get complicated. Here is an example for the first case (assume `Config` is a class in file `global_mod.py`):

```
from global_mod import Config

class foo(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
       # do something with cfg
       y = bar(name='test').start()

       while True:
           pass

    def test(self):
       print('hello world')

class bar(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        # do something with cfg
        # access x.test() from here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cfg = Config()
    x = foo(name='Main').start()
```